# How to populate an Id field that can be referring any of defined models?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building a database using Mongo in which I want a document to have a field that is an ObjectId that can contain the Id of another document model so I can populate it in my queries (in node.js with mongoose).

However, this field, let's call it `eventId`, can refer to any document model in a defined list.

This `Event` model I want would reference a Mongo document model that can be a `Message`, a `Call`, a `File`... Whose Ids are stored in the `eventId` field of my `Event` model. I thought about adding an `eventType` field, which would be an enum with the type of `event` it is, so I would know in which documents find what I'm referring to.

I want to know if it is possible to populate a queried list of `Event` with the documents referred to by the `eventId`, even if those `eventId` don't always refer to the same document type. Specifically, I want to know if there is a way to do it directly in the node.js query, maybe in the same manner allowed by the `populate` method, instead of having to loop over my array and populate it myself by querying manually each and every event.

Comment: Mongodb has this thing called DBRef, which is exactly what you need, a fully qualified ID (with collection and db name). Not sure how that is expressed in mongoose-speak, though.

Comment: Seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. Apparently there's a mongoose-dbref module to use it with mongoose. Thanks !